# Microsoft JWT iss set to sts.windows.net even after changing accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, access-token

I created a new app service and set accessTokenAcceptedVersion to 2 in manifest.json as I am looking for a v2 token similar to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#sample-tokens). However the accessToken generated by Microsoft always has an iss value of sts.windows.net when decoded. I would like it to be login.microsoftonline.com. Please advice.

This is my implementation:

[image]

This is my token when decoded:

[image]

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#what-app-is-a-token-for) (just in the link you shared):

> Resources always own their tokens (those with their `aud` claim) and are
> the only applications that can change their token details. This is why
> changing the access token optional claims for your client does not
> change the access token received when a token is requested for
> `user.read`, which is owned by the Microsoft Graph resource.

It means that the `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` setting should be configured in the service-side app registration rather than client-side app registration.

For an Microsoft Graph token, we are unable to configure it in the service side because the Microsoft Graph app registration is officially managed by Microsoft.

Configuring `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in your client-side won't change the token version to 2. It is expected.

This feature is mainly used when you call you own AAD protected web API, rather than Microsoft official API.

---

UPDATE:

If you want to call you own API, you should create the service-side app registration by [Protected web API: App registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration) and set `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in it.

Here is the complete document for [Scenario: A web app that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).

Comment: Does this mean I need to create two appservices? One for UI and one for ApI?

Comment: @a2441918 You access token is to call Microsoft Graph. In this case you don't need to create an app registration for API because the API is Microsoft Graph.

Comment: @a2441918 In other words, we can't set Microsoft Graph access token version to 2.

Comment: But I dont want to call Microsoft Graph? Is it by default? All I need to do is send the token as Bearer Auth to my Api and validate the token on the api and compare the OID against my database.

Comment: @a2441918 OK got it. I said your access token is for Microsoft Graph because the `aud` is "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", which means this token is for Microsoft Graph. If you want to call you own API, you should create the service-side app registration by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration and set `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in it.

Comment: Thanks man. So two app registrations, one for UI and one for API? Or I just do it for the Api?

Comment: @a2441918 Yes. Two app registrations. Set `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in service-side app registration (API).